# What does it mean that an event happens in theory of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What does it mean that an event happens in probability theory?
Does it mean that one of the outcomes in the event became true or that all outcomes in the event became true?

Comment: In the **theory** of probability, we don't think of events "happening". Events are just sets of outcomes; we don't think of outcomes happening either.

Comment: If we do not think about something happening in the theory of probability probability of what are we calculating?

Comment: Which theory of probability? There is more than one as far as I remember.

Comment: @JamesArathoon, I suppose while discussing the notion of the event you do not stick to any type of the theory since the event should be present in all of them. And in all of them it pose the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an experiment is performed, there is always exactly one outcome.  If that outcome is in the event in question, we say the event occurred.

Comment: Is there a difference whether to say the event is happening or the event is occurring?

Comment: No, they are synonyms.